# Wobble-free progress spinner

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I've been looking for quite some time to fix the wobbly spinner issue. Many people made numerous suggestions using fonts / pure CSS / CSS + JS. Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions were acceptable to me.

The problem with fonts like FontAwesome is that the icon has to be perfectly centered in a container for it not to wobble. Perfect centering with fonts is simply unachievable, since different browsers will render fonts slightly different.

The problem with pure CSS is that most solutions use a font-size and em units to scale spinner elements. em units deliver fractional widths and once again different browsers will yield different results for fractional calculations, resulting in a not perfectly centered spinner.

Even when you build a perfectly centered spinner using javascript, you will notice the wobbly effect at various spinner sizes, while stable at other sizes. After some research, I found the native rotate function also suffers from dealing with fractional dimensions at different scaling.

I ended up building a JavaScript spinner with varying opacity rather than rotating the spinner container, which seems to work wobble free at any modern browser / size / scale. The opacity approach makes background colors blend with the spinner and you can easily change the dimensions or opacity for each spinner hand in the opacity map. [See demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNQJdd).

While this is the best solution I've seen so far, I was wondering if there's a more lightweight approach yielding the same result.

```
function spinner(size) {
    var s=size,n=document.createElement('i'),n1=document.createElement('i'),n2=document.createElement('i'),map=[0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2];
    n.style.cssText='position:relative;display:inline-block;width:'+s+'px;height:'+s+'px;border-radius:100%;margin:20px';
    n1.style.cssText='position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;display:block;width:'+(s/8)+'px;height:'+s+'px;margin-left:'+(-s/16)+'px;border-radius:'+(s/8)+'px;opacity:'+map[0];
    n2.style.cssText='display:block;width:100%;height:30%;background:#000;border-radius:'+(s/8)+'px';
    n1.appendChild(n2);n.appendChild(n1);
    for (var j=1;j<8;j++){var i=n1.cloneNode(true),r='rotate('+(-j*45)+'deg)';i.style.cssText+='opacity:'+map[j]+';transform:'+r+';-webkit-Transform:'+r+';-moz-Transform:'+r+';-ms-Transform:'+r;n.appendChild(i)}
    var f=n.childNodes,a=map.slice(0),b,timer=setInterval(function(){for(j=0;j<f.length;j++){f[j].style.opacity=a[j]};b=a.shift();a.push(b)},125);document.body.appendChild(n);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVqbGW?editors=001)

[Multi-color blending demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNQJdd)

As [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) pointed out, JavaScript timers like `setInterval` should be avoided due to their single-threaded nature. Instead of using the suggested `requestAnimationFrame` I refactored the code using native CSS3 `animation` and it does appear to be slightly smoother. I also fitted the function with an invert option in order to easily switch between light and dark background colors. To create a 24px spinner: call `spinner(24)` on a light background and `spinner(24,1)` on a dark background, as you can see in the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVQjKX?editors=001).

Is there still a better way to create the desired effect?

```
window.onload=function(){document.body.style.background='#888';spinner(12);spinner(16,1);spinner(37);spinner(51,1);spinner(64)}
function spinner(size,invert) {
    var s=size,c='#000',n=document.createElement('i'),n1=document.createElement('i'),n2=document.createElement('i'),y=document.createElement('style'),map=[0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.8];if(invert){c='#fff'};
    n.style.cssText='position:relative;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:'+s+'px;height:'+s+'px;border-radius:100%;margin:20px';
    n1.style.cssText='position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;display:block;width:'+(s/9)+'px;height:'+s+'px;margin-left:'+(-s/18)+'px;border-radius:'+(s/9)+'px;opacity:'+map[0]+';animation:spin 1s infinite steps(8);-webkit-animation:spin 1s infinite steps(8)';
    n2.style.cssText='display:block;width:100%;height:29%;background:'+c+';border-radius:'+(s/9)+'px';n1.appendChild(n2);n.appendChild(n1);
    for (var s=[],j=0;j<=8;j++){s.push((j*12.5)+'%{opacity:'+map[j]+'}');if(j>6){continue};var i=n1.cloneNode(true),r='rotate('+((j+1)*45)+'deg)',d=(j+1)*125;i.style.cssText+='-webkit-animation-delay:'+d+'ms;animation-delay:'+d+'ms;opacity:'+map[j]+';transform:'+r+';-webkit-Transform:'+r+';-moz-Transform:'+r+';-ms-Transform:'+r;n.appendChild(i)};
    y.type='text/css';y.textContent='@-webkit-keyframes spin {'+s.join(' ')+'} @keyframes spin {'+s.join(' ')+'}';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(y);document.body.appendChild(n);
}
```

[JS demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVQjKX?editors=001)

[CSS+JS demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvYzaK?editors=011)

Comment: An animated gif wouldn't suffice? You could include as a `background-image` in your stylesheet, or even lazy load the image depending on if you're using Ajax.

Comment: The idea is to use a resolution independent and lightweight spinner. Animated gifs medieval in my opinion, so I prefer more 'modern' solutions.

Comment: Medieval, but ideal for this scenario. Why don't you make something that gifs can't handle then, like smooth animation or something?

Comment: FYI: setInterval is bad and can be choppy. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Holy compacted code. My eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating all possible ways to create a lightweight and flexible spinner, I ended up using `requestAnimationFrame` which is quite brilliant. It basically does the same thing as CSS3 `animation`: perform calculations and hand the result off to the browser in order to sync repaint with screen redraw (typically at 60fps). While CSS3 `transition` and `animation` are suitable for very basic usage since there's only a `transitionend` event which may not fire under certain circumstances, `requestAnimationFrame` offers full control since you can perform multiple complex calculations and stay in sync with screen redraw.

**CSS**

```
i.spinner {position:relative;display:inline-block;margin:20px}
i.bar {display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;height:inherit}
i.bar i {display:block;width:100%;height:29%;background:#000}
i.bar:nth-child(2) {transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(45deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(3) {transform:rotate(90deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(90deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(90deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(90deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(4) {transform:rotate(135deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(135deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(135deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(135deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(5) {transform:rotate(180deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(180deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(180deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(180deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(6) {transform:rotate(225deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(225deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(225deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(225deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(7) {transform:rotate(270deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(270deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(270deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(270deg)}
i.bar:nth-child(8) {transform:rotate(315deg);-webkit-Transform:rotate(315deg);-moz-Transform:rotate(315deg);-ms-Transform:rotate(315deg)}
```

**JS**

```
function buildspinner(size, invert) {
  var color = '#000',
    spinner = document.createElement('i'),
    bar = document.createElement('i'),
    hand = document.createElement('i'),
    opacitymap = [0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
    nodemap = [];
  if (invert) {color = '#fff'};
  spinner.className = 'spinner';
  spinner.style.cssText = 'width:' + size + 'px;height:' + size + 'px';
  bar.className = 'bar';
  bar.style.cssText = 'width:' + (size / 9) + 'px;height:' + size + 'px;margin-left:' + (-size / 18) + 'px';
  hand.style.cssText = 'border-radius:' + size + 'px;background:' + color;
  bar.appendChild(hand);
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    var clone = bar.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.opacity = opacitymap[j];
    spinner.appendChild(clone);
    nodemap.push(clone)
  }
  document.body.appendChild(spinner);
  requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {animatespinner(timestamp, timestamp, 125, opacitymap, nodemap, 0)})
}

function animatespinner(starttime, timestamp, duration, opacitymap, nodemap, counter) {
  var progress = (timestamp - starttime) / duration;
  counter++;
  if (counter % 3 == 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      var next = j - 1;
      if (next < 0) {
        next = 7
      };
      nodemap[j].style.opacity = (opacitymap[j] + (opacitymap[next] - opacitymap[j]) * progress)
    }
  }
  if (progress < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {animatespinner(starttime, timestamp, 125, opacitymap, nodemap, counter)})
  } else {
    var rotatearray = opacitymap.pop();
    opacitymap.unshift(rotatearray);
    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {animatespinner(timestamp, timestamp, 125, opacitymap, nodemap, 0)})
  }
}
```

The `counter` variable is used for throttling. You want the animation to be smooth, but you want to keep CPU usage low. In this example we change opacity every 3 frames instead of every frame, heavily reducing CPU overhead wihtout noticeable effect on smoothness. (CPU usage was reduced from 12% to 5% on a Quadcore 3GHz processor).

Because CSS3 `animation` relies on `keyframes` you would have to create a separate keyframe for each spinner hand, resulting in way too much calculations. The same spinner built with CSS3 animation resulted in 30% CPU usage.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdJmQZ?editors=011)

Comment: For some weird reason, this one causes 17-20% CPU usage on IE11, while http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvYzaK?editors=011 causes only 8-11%.

Comment: Weird indeed. On webkit it's vice versa.

Comment: But then again, IE has never been a good sport when it comes to honouring standards ?!

Comment: @Ismael Miguel: how's readability working for you now ?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your code is pretty much unreadable. It is easier to read the minified version of jQuery than that. Yes, it's a mish-mash of super-clunky almost-minified unreadable code.

I will review the little I can understand:

1. Your function does too much!

   It appears to have the following functionalities:

   - Stylesheet
   - Inline-stylesheet
   - Element creation
   - Some other obscure functionality

   This function should do 1 thing and do it well, not a bunch of them and doing it ok-ish.
2. The already-mentioned readability
3. Variable names should be descriptive.

   Example of variables you have:

   - `s` - `size` is already perfect
   - `c` - `color` is a candidate, but I don't know where you use it
   - `n` - ...
   - `n1` - ...
   - `n2` - I have no idea
   - `y` - Y U NO USE DESCRIPTIVE NAMES?

   I decided to stop there.
4. You don't validate if `size` is a number.

   What would happen if I run `spinner('testing')`? And `spinner('99999999999999')`?

   It continues executing, without any validation what-so-ever.

   I expect it to throw an `InvalidArgument` exception or `RangeError` or something.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This is about finding the best way to produce a flexible and lightweight spinner. Validation has been left out on purpose since it can easely be fitted in the final candidate. Concerning readability: it's pretty straightforward. n is obviously used for node and n(0-99) for child nodes. y is used for style etc. There is nothing obscure about the code: there is element creation, style creation and finally animation on the created object.

Comment: @Sauvage The whole code is a mish-mash of almost-minified *stuff*. And, I didn't. I understood pretty well the question. Also, [reviewers may comment on any part of the code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I simply picked what I could read.

Comment: Please take a look at my new and improved answer.